# Conditional Formatting - looking up information from another cell?

Tags: excel

We have a show roles rota and not everyone can do every show role. What I'd like to do is highlight when someone is put on the rota in a role they can't do.

For example, Andrew doesn't know the desk. The person doing the rota has forgotten this and put him on the rota on the desk.

What I'd like to happen is for this to turn the cell red to highlight that Andrew doesn't know the desk. I've been trying to do this using conditional formatting but I'm a bit stuck.

I have another sheet with everyone's roles on, with a VLOOKUP so you can lookup what roles people know:

***excel sheet:***
[image]

I'm not really sure what needs to happen to make this work. Any and all suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you post an image of your conditional formatting formula? Which cell should turn red?

Comment: On this show roles, if Andrew is put on the desk I want that cell (the one his name is in) to turn red because he doesn't know that role so I think my conditional formatting needs to reference two cells? [link] https://imgur.com/a/cLssmrm

Comment: So, by "on the desk" you mean Andrew's name shows up somewhere on the shaded grid?

Comment: No, I mean the cell with his name turns red to show that he doesn't know that role. I think I've found the solution using INDEX & MATCH in the conditional formatting: 

INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$H$17,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$17,0),MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$H$1,0))="No"

There's probably more solutions but so far, this one works for me :)

Comment: You could also apply conditional formatting formula `=$H2="NO"` to cells in column A if column H already has a lookup formula in it.